# replace occurrences of string with different values

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, replace, nsstring

I can't find and think of a way of how to replace occurrences of string. E.g I have

```
NSString *str = @"abc abc abc abc abc";
```

After a change I need to have it like this:

```
NSString *str = @"aaa1,aaa2,aaa1,aaa2,aaa1";
```

I guess using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString doesn't fit, so what should I do?

**EDIT:**
Sorry I didn't mentioned, the logic is to replace first found value with aaa1, second found value with aaa2, ant then again the same.
I guess I could show it like this:

```
 if ((the number of founded string) %2 == 0)
    replace with aaa1
 else 
    replace with aaa2
```

**EDIT2**
More example strings and outputs

```
str = @"abc text abc more text abc";
outputStr = @"aaa1 text aaa2 more text aaa1";

str1 = @"abcabcabcabcabc";
str1output = @"aaa1aaa2aaa1aaa2aaa1";
```

Comment: what is the logic here, how are you deciding what the output string should be?

Comment: Is this for some kind of fortune-telling application?

Comment: @wattson12 sorry, see my edit

Comment: Now this makes sense. If you don't even care about the actual original contents - just the number of items - you could just figure out how many items are in original string and construct the result solely with this information. No need to do any string replacement.

Comment: @rokjarc thanks, but that is the point, I need to replace these found strings. E.g my string can be:
@"abc random text abc some more random text abc";
and i need to get this
@"aaa1 random text aaa2 some more random text aaa1";

Comment: Please add more examples of input strings with their appropriate outputs. Because what you just said means that the output of your original example would have to be "aaa1, aaa2, aaa1, aaa2, aaa1" and not "aaa1,aaa2,aaa1,aaa2,aaa1" - unless you want to also trim whitespaces from "random text"

Comment: @rokjarc Edited and added couple of examples more.

Comment: So your first example is wrong?

Comment: @rokjarc not necessarily, i just want an example, a pattern of how to replace the same string with different string values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(NSString *)parseString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog (@"Original input: %@", string);

    NSArray *stringParts = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"abc"];

    NSLog (@"found %d parts", stringParts.count);

    for (NSString *part in stringParts)
    {
        NSLog (@"   '%@'",part);
    }

    NSMutableString *mResult = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    bool toggler = YES;
    bool lastWasEmpty = NO;

    for (NSString *part in stringParts)
    {
        if (!lastWasEmpty)
        {
            [mResult appendFormat:@"aaa%d",toggler?1:2];

            toggler = !toggler;
        }

        [mResult appendString:part];

        lastWasEmpty = !(part && (![part isEqualToString:@""]));
    }

    NSLog (@"Final result: %@", mResult);

    return [NSString stringWithString:mResult];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to:

```
NSArray *myArray = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@", "]];
```

After that you will get an NSArray with all the string components that are comma separated. For example `[myArray objectAtIndex: 0]` will equal to `abc` etc. After that you can replace objects in the array with the desired ones.

```
for (int i=0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {
//Do the changes here. for example

    if (i/2 == 0){
       //add aa2
       } else {
         //add aa1
       }
    }
}
```

Finally you can make the array a NSString again using:

```
NSString * result = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

Comment: My String could be anything, i just made an example, I want to replace first found value with some string, second founded value with another, and then repeat this procedure again, see my edit. Thanks

Comment: anything you mean without a standard pattern? How would you define values then?

Comment: the string can be without commas, maybe i provided a bad example, sorry. See comments for my question.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`NSScanner`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and specifically at `scanUpToString:intoString:`